# Difference between "mandatory" and "indispensable"?

Tags: word-meaning, word-difference

What is the difference between 'mandatory' and 'indispensable'? Can we use them interchangeably? Are there examples which show the difference between both words?

Answer (score 16):

"Mandatory" means that **the thing *must* be done due to some reason or rule.**

> These courses are **mandatory**.

That is, you must take the courses or else you fail.

> Wearing helmets was made **mandatory** a few years ago.

It is a rule that you must wear helmets.

---

"Indispensable" is that the thing is **so critical, useful, or important that you cannot conceivably throw the thing away**.

> The volunteers' help was **indispensible.**

The mission would have failed if the volunteers didn't help.

> He made himself **indispensible** to the parish priest.

He was deemed a must-have person because of some good quality.

> These great tools are so versatile that they are **indispensable**.

The tools are so good that you shouldn't be without them.

---

To sum up, these two words are not interchangeable - they have their own distinct meanings.

Comment: Simple example:  It is mandatory to have a driver's license to drive.  I once drove for about 3 months with my driver's license sitting in a drawer at the library--they forgot to return it, I didn't realize I didn't have it with me.  It certainly wasn't indispensable!

Comment: @LorenPechtel, While a driver's license is mandatory, fuel is indispensable.

Comment: "*The mission might have failed*" If it might have succeeded without the volunteers, they weren't indispensable, only very valuable. "Would" gives the meaning more clearly – the help was instrumental to the success of the mission.

Comment: @RonJensen, [Tesla](http://www.teslamotors.com/) would disagree with that. :-)

Comment: @cjm I said fuel instead of gas hoping it would include electrons. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Very few (if any) words are truly interchangeable, and these two are rarely interchangeable. Both "mandatory" and "indispensable" roughly mean "necessary". But they are used in completely different situations.

"Mandatory" has the nuance of "necessary because of rules and regulations created by someone/group of people" and is usually used with things one must do. e.g.

> - mandatory attendance
> - mandatory minimum sentences for crimes
> - a mandatory meeting

The connotation is neutral to negative. I could imagine a high-school student saying, "Ugh! why is it mandatory that we take 4 years of Math?"

"Indispensable" on the other hand has the nuance of "necessary because other things would fail without it". It is usually used with essential elements of an entire collection of things.

> - An indispensable team member
> - An indispensable ingredient
> - An indispensable tool

The connotation is usually positive.

Comment: +1, but I wouldn't say that "mandatory" is "negative". If you agree with a rule you might think it quite positive.

Comment: @Jay I think the slightly negative connotation of "mandatory" is related to the fact that there is some kind of *mandate* for the mandatory thing. If everyone wanted to do the mandatory thing on their own, there would be no need for a mandate to be issued to make the thing mandatory. Therefore, when something has been made mandatory, it's often *despite* the fact that people **don't** want to do it, not *because* most people *do* want to do it. "Indispensible" connotes something that cannot be dispensed with, meaning it's already being used and is needed so much one couldn't stop using it.

Comment: +1, I would add that "mandatory" doesn't simply have that nuance, but the actual etymological definition, as it derives from **mandate**: *an official order or commission to do something*

Comment: @Sabre Exactly, and as I mention in my earlier comment, "indispensible" also has a built-in etymology from **dispense**: *to throw away or do without*.

Comment: @Sabre True, but be aware of the [etymological fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy).

Comment: @ToddWilcox Sure. I'm just saying that to people who favor the rule, "mandatory" is a good thing. Of course to people who oppose it it's a bad thing. Like I think it's a bad thing that use of fluorescent light bulbs is now mandatory despite their high cost and other drawbacks. But to the people at Phillips who lobbied to get the law passed and who are presumably making billions of dollars from them, that mandate is a great thing.

Comment: @Jay: Can you possibly provide a link to that law?  Or are you talking about a ban on incandescents, which leaves a variety of alternative options, none of which are made mandatory?  (false dichotomy)

Comment: @BenVoigt http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/PLAW-110publ140/html/PLAW-110publ140.htm Yes, yes, the law does not specifically require flourescents: halogen, LED, and other technologies can meet the legal requirements. It does not explicitly ban incandescents. I was trying to give an example to discuss the grammar, not to discuss the details of the law. It is mandatory that you only use light bulbs that meet the lumens/watt and other requirements spelled out in the law.